# pandas dataframe select rows from dataset that match startswith

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, rows

I read data from a csv file and I only need specific columns, I need to select some rows that match the prefix I will pass, I am doing the followiing:

```
account_name = 'Acc1'
df_ec2tpm=pd.read_csv(ec2File, usecols = ["Internal IP", "Instance Id", "PatchGroup","Account"], index_col=3)
df_ec2tpm.loc[df_ec2tpm['Account'].str.startswith(account_name)]
print (df_ec2tpm)
```

If I print the results I see the following:

```
Account,Instance Id,PatchGroup,Internal IP
Acc1-dev,i-0aaa9525f4999999,Windows,192.168.3.20
Acc1-dev,i-0aaa9525f5000000,Windows,192.168.3.21
Acc2-prod,i-0aaa9525f5000001,Windows,192.168.3.22
Acc1-prod,i-0aaa9525f5000002,Windows,192.168.3.23
Acc1-prod,i-0aaa9525f5000003,Windows,192.168.3.24
Acc2-dev,i-0aaa9525f5000004,Windows,192.168.3.25
Acc2-dev,i-0aaa9525f5000005,Windows,192.168.3.26
Acc2-dev,i-0aaa9525f5000006,Windows,192.168.3.27
```

but when I try to select with df_ec2tpm.loc, it is failing with the error

```
 File "C:\Users\marr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Account'
```

What it is wrong?

Ideally, I will do

```
df_ec2=df_ec2tpm.loc[df_ec2tpm['Account'].str.startswith(account_name)]
```

As I need to merge this dataset with another one.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try `df_ec2=df_ec2tpm[df_ec2tpm['Account'].str.startswith(account_name)]`
(no loc)

Comment: @Kate, I just tried but still same error: df_ec2tpm=pd.read_csv(ec2File, usecols = ["Internal IP", "Instance Id", "PatchGroup","Account"], index_col=3)
        df_ec2=df_ec2tpm[df_ec2tpm['Account'].str.startswith(account_name)]

Comment: Also try debugging step-by-step: `mask = df_ec2tmp['Account'].str.startswith(account_name)]` should return a boolean Series'.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that 'Account' is now an index of the data frame, not its column. That's why you are getting KeyError. Just remove `index_col=3`.

Also,
`df_ec2tpm = df_ec2tpm.loc[df_ec2tpm['Account'].str.startswith(account_name), :]`
Slicing outputs a new dataframe without modifying the dataframe in-place.

Comment: I guess I will need to find a way to debug the issue, I tried this answer but still getting same error. I saved the output to a new csv file and I read it the new file, but getting same error when trying to select some rows. I also make sure I don't have empty values in my dataset